# JQuery - function doesn't work on JSON imported data

Tags: jquery, json, append

I have an app that is importing data from JSON and generating (through JQuery's `append()`)a number of html lists representing the data:

```
<ol id="iran">
    <li class="y1900"><p>Iran 1900 Revolution flag</p></li>
    <li class="y1906"><p>Iran 1906 Dictator flag</p></li>
    <li class="y1921"><p>Iran 1921 Revolution flag</p></li>
</ol>
```

I have a function `resizeFlags()` that (purely for UI) calculates the widths of each list item and resizes to fit everything into one screen.

The `resizeFlags()` function is called during `$(document).ready()` (after the JSON load) and works fine with my test (static) html file, but does not work when the test html is removed and the same html is appended using the JSON data - the appended lists enter the DOM properly, but the resizing does not happen.

I have a manual trigger for `resizeFlags()` (for recalculating based on a new year range) and that works as expected on the appended data.

I feel like it's something obvious that I've overlooked - what am I missing?

Edit:

Here's the code that appends the data (I've temporarily moved `resizeFlags()` into this function, normally it's called straight after:

```
function loadFlags() {
$.getJSON('data/flags.json',function(countriesdata){
    //for each flag
    $.each(countriesdata.countries,function(i,countries){
        $('#countries').append('<li id="'+countries.country+'">'+countries.country+'</li>')
        $('#flags').append('<ol id="'+countries.country+'"></ol>')
        $.each(countries.years,function(i,flagyears){
            $('#flags #'+countries.country).append('<li class="y'+flagyears.year+' '+flagyears.taxonomy+'"><p>'+flagyears.flagname+'</p></li>')
        });
    });
});
//resize from defaults
resizeFlags(totalYears);
}
```

Comment: how are you laoding the JSON? Your document is only JSON? $(document).ready() is not launched after an ajax call for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax calls (like [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)) are asynchronous. 
That means that even if you make the JSON call right before you trigger the `resizeFlags()` function in document ready the response might not have arrived yet.

The only way to make sure `resizeFlags()` is called at the right time is to put it in the success handler, like so:

```
$.getJSON('some-url', function(data) {
  //1. do something with the data (like build the list, append elements to the DOM)
  //...
  //2. call other UI stuff, after the elements created above are inserted in the DOM
  resizeFlags();
});
```

The following would work only if the JSON response is received really fast (before the more code stuff gets executed):

```
$.getJSON(...);
//some more code
resizeFlags();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `resizeFlags(totalYears);` outside of the callback function of the JSON query. This is called instantaneously even before the JSON data is returned. Put that line inside the JSON success callback once the each loop is compeleted

Answer (score 0):

You need to call resizeFlags after the getJSON call completes, i.e at the end of the insertion function. Otherwise those element's won't be present when the resize occurs

Answer (score 0):

After you append the JSON data, you will need to call your resizeFlags() function.

If the resizeFlags() could be done in CSS, then you would not need to call resizeFlags() again.

Comment: For context, the UI needs to animate (there's a lot going on and if it just changed suddenly it would be confusing for the user). 

At the moment it's more stable to use JQuery's animate() than CSS3 transforms, but I do plan on letting CSS handle all the animations eventually. Thanks :)